# Move Mouse Cursor Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mouse, mouseevent

I'm building a joke microsite for a company. They want a feature where the mouse cursor will randomly change position when the user hovers over a certain image.

Is this possible in Javascript? How would I implement it?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I know this is a really annoying feature, but its what the client wants.

Comment: So, what where you're proposed alternatives to this terrible requirement that you did not convince the client?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't... but you can - in a way.

What you can do to mimic this behavior is that you can hide the actual cursor with css `cursor: none` and then create an image representing the cursor which would look the same and would be placed in position of the real cursor. Then whe user would move the mouse you'd have to update the position of the cursor image and apply your random position changes as you wish - though be aware that when user will scroll outside of the browser content window (on the controls or outside the browser) they will get their mouse cursor back to real position and your cursor will be stuck in its last position.

The only way you could pull this prank out. Good luck with it and hope they'll enjoy it ;)

PS.

inverting the mouse movement direction can be funny as well :>

Comment: Why the hell would you enable this kind of development?  I need to set you on fire, Tom.

Comment: Yes, just set the mice on him!

Answer (score 1):

You can't move the mouse cursor.

You can move the page or the image relative to the position of the cursor, which might make it look like the cursor moved when it didn't?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your cursor with invisible custom icon, and then make a fake cursor and move it.