# js: stop mouse movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse

it's possible to stop mouse movement in window and allow only in certain box ?

for example, i have a `div` with `width: 200px` and `height: 200px`, to allow only in this div to move mouse.

Thank you.

Comment: No - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415345/javascript-how-to-stop-mouse-movement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415345/javascript-how-to-stop-mouse-movement)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep mouse inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730433/keep-mouse-inside-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript can read mouse position but not set it. 
What I would do for that kind of things is place an element under the mouse and prevent the page element from moving outside of the bounds even.

Also I have seen this link in stackoverflow, maybe it can help you

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API

Comment: this work, but it is a solution to stop confirmation of browser?

Comment: @Firuza Absolutely not, what are you trying to create?