# Limit mousemove event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove

how can i limit the mousemove event to a certain area, let's say a div in the middle of the page? Thanks in advance

```
if (window.screen.width > 765)
if (matchMedia('(pointer:fine)').matches) 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).on("mousemove", function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var el = $(".title");
    el.css('position', 'absolute');
    el.css("left", x);
    el.css("top", y);
  })
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep mouse inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730433/keep-mouse-inside-a-div)

Comment: Assign the event to the `div` instead of the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you just need to attach the `mouseevent` to the target element, you need the `mouseevent` limit to

```js
$('#specificDiv').on("mousemove", function(e) {
  var offset = $(this).offset();

  var x = e.pageX - offset.left;
  var y = e.pageY - offset.top;

  var el = $(".title");
  el.css('position', 'absolute');
  el.css("left", x);
  el.css("top", y);
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#specificDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="specificDiv">
  <div class="title">title</div>
</div>
```