# Place pointer on div or other page element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to help the site visitor navigate a page on my site.  For this I'd like to have a javascript auto navigation that will place the pointer on different page elements.  Is there a way in javascript to place the pointer on the desired page elements: div, button, span...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question asked here : [Move Mouse Cursor Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804068/move-mouse-cursor-javascript)

Basically your options are using the method in the linked post, or using libraries like http://amberjack2.org/ to visually guide your users around the page / site.

Answer (score 0):

you can not move the pointer using javascript. you can only set the focus to an element of your choice.